# Remove element after fading

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a plugin I have the following:

```
var defaults = {
    hide: function ($element, $tooltip) {
        $tooltip.fadeOut(4000);
    }
};
$(this).each(function (e) {
    $this.mouseleave(function (e) {
        tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            options.hide($this, $("." + options.class).stop(true, true), function () {
                $("." + options.class).remove(); // THE ELEMENT IS NOT BEING REMOVED
            });
        }, 0);
    }), // Mouse leave  
})
```

On mouse leave I am trying to remove the element after the animation ends.

The problem is that the element is not being removed. But it works if I use:

```
$this.mouseleave(function (e) {
    tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
        options.hide($this, $("." + options.class).stop(true, true));
        $("." + options.class).remove(); // THE ELEMENT IS BEING REMOVED
    }, 0);
}), // Mouse leave
```

Then everything works fine ... Why is function() { ... } disable the remove action?

Comment: what if you do this - `$(this).mouseleave(function (e) {`

Comment: That does not solve it ... I have an online example: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/nJeFi ... What I have seems logic but some how it is not working. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: @wirey He's using `.hide( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )`

Comment: The reason why I have a hide function in defaults is because I would like to allow, who uses the tooltip, to use custom animations to show or hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the third parameter (the callback) that way. Try this:

```
var defaults = {
    hide: function ($element, $tooltip, $func) {
        if(typeof $func === 'function');
            $tooltip.fadeOut(4000, 'swing', $func);
        else
            $tooltip.fadeOut(4000);
    }
};

$(this).each(function (e) {
    $this.mouseleave(function (e) {
        tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            options.hide($this, $("." + options.class).stop(true, true), function () {
                $("." + options.class).remove(); // THE ELEMENT IS NOT BEING REMOVED
            });
        }, 0);
    }), // Mouse leave  
})
```

**Edit:**

Demo on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wcX3g/

Comment: That does not solve it ... I added the example in http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/nJeFi

Comment: I've improved my answer and did some tests on JSFiddle (CodePen didn't impress me). I'm sure it reaches the `$("." + options.class).remove();` line now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to different `this`, one is `$(this)` which so far makes no reference to any element, and then you have `$this` inside `$(this).each()`, Who is $(this)???, I think you need another selector for your elements, like $('.className'). Then inside you can use $(this) for each element with the same className:

```
$('.myClass').each(function (e) {
    $(this).mouseleave(function (e) {
        tooltip.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            options.hide($this, $("." + options.class).stop(true, true), function () {
                $("." + options.class).remove(); 
            });
        }, 0);
    }),  
})
```

Maybe you can use Jquery hover:

```
$(this).hover(function(){
    //on mouse over
}, function(){
    //on mouse out
    $(the_elm_toRemove).remove();
});
```

Comment: I am using $this to cache $(this). Please, check my online example in http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/nJeFi

Comment: Oh I see, have you considered hover? Look at my answer I added some new code, it might help :)